# How can I get value from object with nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a nested JSON. How can I extract value for the object and nested object together?

Here is the example:

```
const person = [
   {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Bob',
      address: {
         country: 'United State',
         city: 'New York'
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Vegan',
      address: {
         country: 'Los Angeles',
         city: 'New York'
      }
    }
]
```

How can I get value of `name` with `country` properties in the same time?

Comment: Hi Buang, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "in the same time", but the javascript accessor operator is `.`. So, to get the name and country of the first member in your list, you would right: 

`const name = person[0].name`
`const country = person[0].address.country`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), something like this

```
const person = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    address: {
      country: 'United State',
      city: 'New York'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Vegan',
    address: {
      country: 'Los Angeles',
      city: 'New York'
    }
  }
]

const list = person.reduce((list, item) => {
  return list.concat({
    name: item.name,
    country: item.address.country
  })
}, [])

console.log(list);
```

Comment: thanks so much bro, i had tried with spread operator before to merge two different object, like first I get value for name then declare a new object to get value of country. but it does'nt work.